# Calling any sort of field in async def causes error

Tags: discord.py

So I’m making a discord bot that creates a profile for a user based off of their username and userID. The userID is the unique identifier for the profile, and the username is what is responded and searched when looking for said profile.
In order to get the userID and username, I’ve been trying to use `discord.User`, and getting the userID then transferring that to a username, both return with this error:

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEcb1.jpg)

I can’t figure out how to fix this, I’ve tried many different ways of getting the username and ID, but they all return a similar error.
Packages:

Discord, discord.ext, replit, os, db(replit extension)

Language:
Python V 3.8.0

Code:

```
@bot.command()
async def create(ctx, message):
  user_id = message.author.id
  userName = bot.get_user(user_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `ctx` - you don't need `message`. Also, if you just want the username and ID of the person who calls the command, you don't even need to use `discord.User`.

```py
@bot.command()
async def create(ctx):
  user_id = ctx.author.id
  user_name = ctx.author.name
```